# How to deploy separated frontend and backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, frontend, backend

I am developing a new project with react/express as the frontend and loopback as the backend api. I have separated both of them in my development environment with different ports.

How should I deploy them in production?

1. Hosting on a same server - separate the backend with a different sub-domain?
2. Hosting on 2 different servers - seems impossible to use back the same domain.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I just answered [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250688/652669) for AWS.

You can deploy

- your **frontend** on a **static hosting service** and a **CDN**

  - [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3) + [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront)
  - [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) + [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn)
  - [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) + [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com)
  - [Now](https://zeit.co/now)
  - [Surge](https://surge.sh)
  - [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com)
  - etc
- your **backend** on a **cloud computing service**

  - [AWS Elastic beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk) or [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2)
  - [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine)
  - [Now](https://zeit.co/now)
  - [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)
  - etc

You can set different subdomains on different hosts, e.g.

- `app.domain.com` on GitHub Pages
- `api.domain.com` on Heroku

Comment: Great answer, thanks, helped me a lot. Just have an additional question. In this case, how many instances of containers should I use for frontend and backend? I know for the backend since it accepts a lot of incoming requests, a load balancer and several instances should be deployed. But how about frontend, should I use equal amount or just one instance since I already have CDN?

Comment: "just one instance since I already have CDN" - yes just one. It's the CDN's job to make it scale.

Comment: What about CORS and/if using httpOnly cookies?

Comment: What about SSR (Next.js for example)? Your frontend then needs to run Node.js.

Comment: @GG., this is a great answer. Any documentation out there on how to get that backend Heroku talking to the frontend on S3 + Cloudfront?

Comment: Good summary. The CORS issue needed some mentions though

Comment: I don't know why people don't want to use or utilize nginx approach ? Just deploy your frontend on an nginx/httpd etc.. then apply proxies as per your APIs towards related endpoints.

Comment: @OlgunKaya you don't need a web server to serve a static file.